# Does Redis RDB run bgsave or save?

Tags: redis

I am using Redis as more of a temporary store, but there are some fields that I want to persist, so I want to use RDB. A few minutes lost will not hurt. However I am noticing that at times I get big IO Wait spikes on my server and I believe it is when an RDB save is occurring.

I found that there are two commands when running manually, BGSAVE and SAVE. They do the same thing, but BGSAVE allows for background saving to ensure that redis does not block any new writes/reads.

The config file for saving has lines similar to:

```
save 10 1000

save 100 500
```

Is this literally meaning that it is using the SAVE command and if so, can I replace that with bgsave and get my expected/needed results?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The configuration's `save` directive invokes the same mechanism as `BGSAVE`, i.e. it will not block the server. I totally understand, however, why this is confusing.

Comment: Thank you, Itamar. This helps me ensure my IO situation has a separate cause. I just wanted to be certain it wasn't something as obvious as using BGSAVE instead of SAVE.